# yii2 advanced template: logging in causes inifinite redirect loop

Tags: php, nginx, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've finished and uploaded my yii2 project (advanced template) to hosting (runs on nginx 1.4.4). Now when I want to log in to administrative backend and enter the login/password, it starts an infinite redirect loop. Which in my localserver it does not behave such that.

I've surfed across the net but can't find any answer. Hope someone have faced such situation and were able to figure out, what is the problem.

Some details:

Server: nginx 1.4.4;
X-Cacheable: YES
Varnish is also enabled.

I can give more information if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should seperate application into 2 parts. Keep frontend session and backend session seperately. And read this guide . Recommended Nginx Configuration
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

```html
server {
    charset utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 128M;

    listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name mysite.local;
    root        /path/to/basic/web;
    index       index.php;

    access_log  /path/to/basic/log/access.log;
    error_log   /path/to/basic/log/error.log;

    location / {
        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    # uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
    #location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    #    try_files $uri =404;
    #}
    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
        deny all;
    }
}
```